# mod_rewrite .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

For some weird reason this works on localhost but doesn't work on remote server

---to remove .php extension from ALL php files

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What happens on the remote server?

Comment: Not rewriting URLs of /index to /index.php internally

Comment: Check your Apache error logs and see where it's redirecting to and post that here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. You do this by putting

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And adding this to top of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in you httpd.conf file.

Comment: and placing "RewriteEngine On" (without the quotes) towards the top of the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

also ensure that if your code is accessed in a subdirectory on the remote server, you set the correct RewriteBase in your .htaccess